# PHAssetResourceManager's requestData Returning multiple objects

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

I am trying to get the Data value of a `PHAssetResource` so I can make a `CGImageSource` with it like so:

```
let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: imageAsset)
let fullSizePhotoResources = resources.filter { $0.type == .fullSizePhoto }
let targetResource = fullSizePhotoResources[0]

let resourceManager = PHAssetResourceManager()

resourceManager.requestData(for: targetResource, options: nil, dataReceivedHandler: { (resourceData) in

                            let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(resourceData as CFData, nil)
                            print("data: \(resourceData)")
                            handler(self.getDataFromImageSource(imageSource: imageSource))

                        }) { (inError) in

                            if inError != nil {
                                //handle error
                            }
                        }
```

however, instead of returning one data object, I am receiving three. So the print statement prints this:

```
data: 1048576 bytes
data: 972120 bytes
data: 0 bytes
```

I am not sure what all these three objects are but only the first one results in the `CGImageSource` that I want. The problem is that I have no way of stopping the request when I receive the first object so It keeps calling the handler over and over. I tried calling the cancelDataRequest method inside getDataFromImageSource but I get an error saying that data was not completely loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetresourcemanager/1616279-requestdata) for `requestData`:

> While reading (or downloading) asset resource data, Photos calls your `handler` block at least once, progressively providing chunks of data. After reading all of the data, Photos calls your `completionHandler` block to indicate that the data is complete. (At this point, the complete data for the asset is the concatenation of the `data` parameters from all calls to your `handler` block.) If Photos cannot finish reading or downloading asset resource data, it calls your `completionHandler` block with a description of the error. Photos can also call the `completionHandler` block with a non-nil error when the data is complete if the user cancels downloading.

So you need to build up the data from each call to the closure and then in the completion handler you can do something with that complete data.

```
var imageData = Data()
resourceManager.requestData(for: targetResource, options: nil, dataReceivedHandler: { (resourceData) in
    imageData.append(resourceData)
}) { (inError) in
    if let error = inError {
        //handle error
    } else {
        let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)
        print("data: \(resourceData)")
        handler(self.getDataFromImageSource(imageSource: imageSource))
    }
}
```